# How to write this kind of SQL statement in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables just like this:

```
table one: myjobs
name,first_job,second_job

table two: jobs
code,name
```

I only store job's code in myjobs table, and I want to show the both job's name in one SQL statement,how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that your table structure is awful you have to join the same table twice

```
select m.name, f.name as first, s.name as second
from myjobs m
left join jobs f on f.code = m.first_job
left join jobs s on s.code = m.second_job
```